# Android displaying listFragment in a navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-listfragment

It seems for me that the replace method for fragments does not work with list fragments. This code gives me an error:

```
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, mFragment).commit();
```

How do I display list fragments in a navigation drawer? Is there any other way?

The error I receive is that:

> The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is
>   not applicable for the arguments (int, ListFragment)

It says that it's not applicable. When I changed the list fragment class into a fragment only, my problem is that I cannot set also the adapter for a list view which is the setListAdapter. Can someone help me please?

Comment: When you are asking about some programming problem because of an error, the first thing that you have to do is to tell what error you receive. Copying the entire error is the best you can do.

Comment: `mFragment` is a `Fragment` and you have to use a `ListFragment` as a parameter.

Comment: Yes I'm making sure that the arguments that I placed is a ListFragment. I still got an error. :(

Comment: The error don't says so. You are using a `Fragment` instead of a `ListFragment`.

Comment: Hello I managed to get it to display to list fragment sorry for my mistake. xD
But the one's that I get to display is a dummy data..
Now my problem is that how can I set the ListFragment's setListAdapter?

Comment: It's because I'm making a custom adapter for my listview in the list fragment..

Comment: Sorry but that's difficult for me, I'm not an Android developer. I pointed out your problem because the error was explicit, but actually I don't know what a `Fragment` is xD If is a different error ask a new question so a qualified Android developer will reply. I'll add my reply as an answer as it was a correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mFragment` is a `Fragment` and you have to use a `ListFragment` as a parameter.